# How to get frp partition via cmd in scatter file

Tags: android, batch-file

How can I get and echo only the `partition_index: SYS18` , `linear_start_addr: 0x8020000`, `physical_start_addr: 0x8020000` and `partition_size: 0x100000`?

In addition scatter.txt may vary depends on android device model.

I need to get only the frp part of the `scatter.txt`.

```
  partition_index: SYS17
  partition_name: metadata
  file_name: NONE
  is_download: false
  type: NORMAL_ROM
  linear_start_addr: 0x6020000
  physical_start_addr: 0x6020000
  partition_size: 0x2000000
  region: EMMC_USER
  storage: HW_STORAGE_EMMC
  boundary_check: true
  is_reserved: false
  operation_type: INVISIBLE
  reserve: 0x00

  partition_index: SYS18
  partition_name: frp
  file_name: NONE
  is_download: false
  type: NORMAL_ROM
  linear_start_addr: 0x8020000
  physical_start_addr: 0x8020000
  partition_size: 0x100000
  region: EMMC_USER
  storage: HW_STORAGE_EMMC
  boundary_check: true
  is_reserved: false
  operation_type: PROTECTED
  reserve: 0x00

  partition_index: SYS19
  partition_name: pad
  file_name: NONE
  is_download: false
  type: NORMAL_ROM
  linear_start_addr: 0x8120000
  physical_start_addr: 0x8120000
  partition_size: 0x6E0000
  region: EMMC_USER
  storage: HW_STORAGE_EMMC
  boundary_check: true
  is_reserved: false
  operation_type: INVISIBLE
  reserve: 0x00
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@echo off&SetLocal EnableDelayEdexpansion
set /a n = 1
for /f "delims=" %%a in (scatter.txt) do (
  set "b=%%a"
  set "b=!b:partition_index=!"
  set "b=!b:linear_start_addr=!"
  set "b=!b:physical_start_addr=!"
  set "b=!b:partition_size=!"
  if not "!b!" equ "%%a" (
    if defined flag set /a n+=1
    call set str!n!=%%a
  )

  set "b=!b:partition_name: frp=!"
  if "!b!" equ "" set flag=1
)
for /l %%a in (1 1 4) do (
  echo !str%%a!
)

pause
```

Comment: `findstr /R "^partition ^linear ^physical" "scatter.txt"` is the same as your script however it would not extract desired part with `partition_name: frp` line!

Comment: Thanks for reply sir Xingxing Qiao your code is nice but i need only the frp line.

Comment: i tried your code but the output is   partition_size: 0x80000
ECHO is off.
ECHO is off.
ECHO is off.
Press any key to continue . . .

Comment: `set "b=!b:partition_name: frp=!"` in this line `partition_name: frp` must be       exact same with frp line in the scatter.txt.  JosefZ's method is adaptable and better.

Answer (score 0):

The following *commented* script should do the job. Note that `delims` slightly differ in two `for /F` loops:

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion

set "_word=%~1"                         for debugging purposes
if not defined _word set "_word=frp"    default value of partition name

set "_right="                           remove variable _right

                  REM iteration #1: GET sequence number of a data block
set "_index=0"
for /F "tokens=1,* delims=: " %%G in ('
    findstr /R "partition_index partition_name" "D:\bat\SO\files\scatter.txt"
    ') do (
  if "%%~G"=="partition_index" set /A _index+=1
  if "%%~G"=="partition_name" if "%%~H"=="%_word%" set /A _right=_index  
)

if not defined _right (
    echo %_word% not found as partition_name
    goto :endscript
)

                  REM iteration #2: USE sequence number of a data block
set "_index=0"
for /F "tokens=1,* delims=:" %%G in ('
    findstr /R "partition linear physical" "D:\bat\SO\files\scatter.txt"
    ') do (
  if "%%~G"=="partition_index" set /A _index+=1
  if %_right% EQU !_index! echo %%G:%%H

)
:endscript
ENDLOCAL
goto :eof
```

**Output**:

```
==> D:\bat\SO\42691448.bat xxx
xxx not found as partition_name

==> D:\bat\SO\42691448.bat metadata
partition_index: SYS17
partition_name: metadata
linear_start_addr: 0x6020000
physical_start_addr: 0x6020000
partition_size: 0x2000000

==> D:\bat\SO\42691448.bat
partition_index: SYS18
partition_name: frp
linear_start_addr: 0x8020000
physical_start_addr: 0x8020000
partition_size: 0x100000

==>
```

**Resources** (required reading):

- (command reference) [An A-Z Index of the Windows CMD command line](http://ss64.com/nt/)
- (helpful particularities) [Windows CMD Shell Command Line Syntax](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax.html)
- (`%~G` etc. special page) [Command Line arguments (Parameters)](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-args.html)
- (special page) [EnableDelayedExpansion](http://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html)
- (`>>`, `2>&1` etc. special page) [Redirection](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-redirection.html)

Comment: Your code is working sir for SYS17 to SYS19 im sorry but i forgot that there is also SYS0 upto SYS24 for the whole scatter.txt depending for every unit. So my expectation is if there is frp in scatter file it will get the frp line and its linear_start_addr: 0x8020000 ,physical_start_addr: 0x8020000 and its partition_size: 0x100000 if there is no frp then echo FRP Not found...

Comment: I do not expect that there might be more partitions of the same name however I _know_ a solution for the case (by a minor adaptation of the current one).   The case _if there is no frp_ is already covered, see `echo %_word% not found as partition_name` line in the script and `xxx not found as partition_name` in the output (for a fictional `xxx` partition name).

Comment: Yes your were right sir you have included the "%_word% not found as partition_name" and i thank for your effort sir and i'm sorry for not stating that there are more partition that i did not included. In addition scatter.txt may vary depends on model.

Comment: @Drxtool If my answer was helpful, please consider marking it as accepted. [See this page](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/) for an explanation of why this is important. If current solution does not work for another data set, then feel free to ask another question (providing link to this one along with  a [mcve]). You could be interested in following links to (IMHO very good) `cmd` and `.bat` scripting: https://ss64.com/nt/ and https://ss64.com/nt/syntax.html

Comment: Though its output is it not exactly what im looking but it is very helpful sir JosefZ for it gives more idea and i love to consider marking it as accepted but im waiting for another answer.